# c# how can i view my datasource?

Tags: c#, data-binding

i am debugging a `datagridview1.datasource`

how can i see the actual data that is stored inside `datasource`?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio...

Comment: just add a watch in the debugger

Comment: @doggett what exactly what i watch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't know how to add the watch, so here's how.

While the program is running go to the main window of Visual Studio and select Debug->Windows->Watch, this will open and select the watch window.

Just type `dataGridView1.DataSource` in there and it'll show all the values it holds

Since it's a dataset, you can type

```
((DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource).Tables[0].Rows
```

Or use `dataGridView1.DataMember` instead of `0` if it gives you the wrong table..

But it's still hard to navigate through, you have to then go to `Non-Public Members` then `List` and then `Results View` but each row as a seperate `ItemArray`, so depending on what you're trying to see it can be a pain..

Comment: thats great but what exactly would i watch. it has a million properties/methods, how do i know what to look for

Comment: Ah ok, can you tell me what type the watch window shows it is (last column)?